# No response to compile request in MavensMate this morning

Tags: performance, mavensmate

This morning when compiling classes to server in one of my sandboxes, the files are "spinning" forever in MM's status window.

[image: a lot of these..]

But if I open the classes list in the browser, I can see that the classes are being saved successfully, and very quickly.  Somehow that news isn't making it back to MM.

Any ideas here?  Haven't run into this before.  Tried both tooling and regular.  Only thing I can think of is I'm on Windows and I just patched the OS.  Could it be blocking a port that MM needs or something?  Running an async unit test on same server works fine, though.

Comment: I was having the same issues this morning but I blamed my slow network and even salesforce servers The problem was solved a few hours later. Are you still experiencing this?

Comment: Yes.  Still happening for me.

Comment: And my first thought was SF slowness too.  But I tried upping the timeout in SF, and can see that the compile is succeeding long before the timeout.  So unless it's just the response that's delayed, that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: Hmm, working now, after over an hour of not working.  Guess it was just waiting for me to post about it here.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved itself eventually and spontaneously.